# Linux Mint / Realtek RTL8101/2/6E Ethernet Connection issues

Tags: ethernet, internet

I recently switched to a wired connection on my Linux Mint 18 machine, only to find it does not work. Here is my system info:

```
uname -a: Linux bric 4.4.0-71-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 24 12:59:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci | grep Ethernet: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)

sudo ethtool -i enp2s0:
driver: r8101
version: 1.031.02-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

ifconfig:
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:44:fa:1c  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:25 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:4915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:430649 (430.6 KB)  TX bytes:430649 (430.6 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:5d:43:e4:9c:88  
      inet addr:145.94.206.30  Bcast:145.94.207.255 Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c21e:b30b:eac2:8f6e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:13740 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:11594148 (11.5 MB)  TX bytes:3055045 (3.0 MB)
```

When I plug in an ethernet cable, it doesn't seem to recognize it, and in the Network Settings it still says "Cable Unplugged".

***Attempts***
So far I have tried the r8101 (currently active), r8168, and r8169 (originally active) Realtek drivers. Both the r8101 and r8169 drivers shows the Cable Unplugged status while the r8168 driver completely removed the ethernet interface.

Please let me know if you need any additional information to help with this issue.